# Where is Meteor data in Mongo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I was coding along with the Meteor simple colours [example screencast](http://meteor.com/screencast). After inserting some colours into the database via the Chrome JS Console (1:08 in the video):

```
Colors.insert({name: "red"});
Colors.insert({name: "green"});
```

I wanted to see if I could find this same data in the mongo console:

```
$ meteor mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.1
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3002/meteor
> show dbs
local   (empty)
meteor  0.0625GB
> use meteor
switched to db meteor
> show collections
colors)
system.indexes
> db.colors.find()
>
```

Nothing.

Why is there no data in there?

Also why is there a ")" after the "colors" collection name, is that related?

This is my .js file:

```
Colors = new Meteor.Collection("colors)");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.colour_list.colors = function()
  {
    return Colors.find({}, {sort : {likes: -1, name: 1}});
  };
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, remove your ) and try again ...

```
Colors = new Meteor.Collection("colors");
```

Comment: Thanks. Very embarrassing.